# python FastAPI websocket, Popen - print device stdout works, but stdout to websocket client doesn't

Tags: python, websocket, stdout, fastapi, popen

I have a websocket server and a js/html client. When I click a button on the client, it invokes a shell command on the server.
I use Popen to call the command cat /dev/ttyUSB0 to read the content of a device which is constantly changing. When I print the output on terminal it works, but when I send the output through the websocket it doesn't do anything until I interrupt the program. I don't know what's happening.

This is what i've tried

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import json
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
import shlex

app = FastAPI()
html = open('templates/index.html').read()

@app.get("/")
async def get():
    return HTMLResponse(html)
```

Here's where the problem occur

```py
async def run_command(websocket: WebSocket):
    print("running command")
    command = "cat /dev/ttyUSB0"
    args = shlex.split(command)

    with Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT) as process:
        for output in process.stdout:   
            await websocket.send_text(output.decode())
            # print(output.decode(), end='')
```

I tried to send just one readline and it worked, except in a while loop

```py
await websocket.send_text( process.stdout.readline() )
```

Route

```py
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        message = None
        data = await websocket.receive_text()

        try:
            message = json.loads(data)
        except:
            await websocket.send_text("Bad message")

        if message.get("type") == "monitor":
            await websocket.send_text("Uploading project")
            await run_command(websocket)
```

client

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="sendMessage(event)">
    <button>Send</button>
</form>
<ul id='output'></ul>
<script>
      var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws");
      ws.onmessage = function(event) { console.log(event.data) };

      function sendMessage(event) {
            var input = document.getElementById("messageText")
            ws.send('{"type": "monitor"}')
            event.preventDefault()
      }
</script>
```

Comment: As I see you need to create SSE (server side event), to do that you need to make your response function work as a generator, using `yield` and to make it work you need to send it as `yield f"data: {decoded_output} \n\n"` or just return the decoded_output